# Hudson SVN plugins makes exception for private repository updates

Tags: svn, exception, hudson, hudson-plugins

I'm new user of Hudson.

I'm running the Hudson in my company network. The source codes for my projects are in the repository of other IDC. The repository itself doen't allow public connection, so we makes a slave node machine for Hudson which can connect to the repository. When I make Hudson projects, I use repository URL only available for the slave node.

Whe polling SCM it's okay to connect, and the source code update seems okay, too. But the SVN plugin raise exceptions right after the update finish. Here is the log.

```
Started by user xster
Building remotely on XXXBuilder
Updating https://myprivaterepository/myproject/trunk
U         projectsource1
U         projectsource2
At revision 10498
hudson.util.IOException2: revision check failed on https://myprivaterepository/myproject/trunk
 at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogBuilder.buildModule(SubversionChangeLogBuilder.java:157)
 at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogBuilder.run(SubversionChangeLogBuilder.java:99)
 at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.calcChangeLog(SubversionSCM.java:504)
 at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:621)
 at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1119)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:479)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:411)
 at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1324)
 at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:139)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: unknown host
svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/myproject/trunk'
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:103)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:87)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:616)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:273)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:261)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:516)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:98)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1001)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getLatestRevision(DAVRepository.java:178)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNBasicClient.getRevisionNumber(SVNBasicClient.java:482)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNBasicClient.getLocations(SVNBasicClient.java:851)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNBasicClient.createRepository(SVNBasicClient.java:534)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNLogClient.doLog(SVNLogClient.java:1016)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNLogClient.doLog(SVNLogClient.java:891)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNLogClient.doLog(SVNLogClient.java:823)
 at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogBuilder.buildModule(SubversionChangeLogBuilder.java:145)
 ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: myprivaterepository
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1201)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1128)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1064)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1014)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory.createAddres(SVNSocketFactory.java:132)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory.createSSLSocket(SVNSocketFactory.java:67)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.connect(HTTPConnection.java:183)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:323)
 ... 23 more
[WARNINGS] Skipping publisher since build result is FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

if I change hostname to ip, I got this message

```
hudson.util.IOException2: revision check failed on https://111.111.111.111/myproject/trunk
 at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogBuilder.buildModule(SubversionChangeLogBuilder.java:157)
 at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogBuilder.run(SubversionChangeLogBuilder.java:99)
 at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.calcChangeLog(SubversionSCM.java:504)
 at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:621)
 at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1119)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:479)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:411)
 at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1324)
 at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:139)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: timed out waiting for server
svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/myproject/trunk'
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:103)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:87)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:616)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:273)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:261)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:516)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:98)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1001)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getLatestRevision(DAVRepository.java:178)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNBasicClient.getRevisionNumber(SVNBasicClient.java:482)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNBasicClient.getLocations(SVNBasicClient.java:851)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNBasicClient.createRepository(SVNBasicClient.java:534)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNLogClient.doLog(SVNLogClient.java:1016)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNLogClient.doLog(SVNLogClient.java:891)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNLogClient.doLog(SVNLogClient.java:823)
 at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogBuilder.buildModule(SubversionChangeLogBuilder.java:145)
 ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:310)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:176)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:163)
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:384)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:579)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketConnection.run(SVNSocketConnection.java:57)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
[WARNINGS] Skipping publisher since build result is FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any idea to solve problem? or bypass?

Comment: Does http://hudson.361315.n4.nabble.com/SCM-revision-check-failed-td1459196.html helps?

Comment: It's the same situation I have. But I don't use Jetty. I am using standalone version. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Check if there are some stored credentials, for the user running the slaves. Whats the slave OS (Windows, Linux, Unix)? How is the slave set up (as a service, stop and started by slave machine, stop and started by Master, e.g. ssh nodes)? Check the error message, that the URL (https://myprivaterepository/myproject/trunk) is correct (upper and lower case is important).

Comment: Did you tried the same steps manually on the slave machine? Of course, you should connect with the same credentials that Hudson uses and also use the same credentials for SVN.

Comment: Did you try the IP instead of the hostname? For some people with similar issues it helped.

Comment: i use stored credentials, solaris 10 slave, ssh nodes, no special error message on master service. i stored credentials by checkout manually. using IP, i got different error message (timeout). I updated original post.

Comment: I moved the hudson service into my IDC which can connect repository directly. The problem is disappeared, but I can't use my AD server, and other build machines which are in my office.

Answer (score 0):

we've just experienced such problem in the last few days and got a resolution:

the XUnit plugin was recently installed on Jenkins, only then our XP slave started to behave by throwing exception (revision check failed) when the build was triggered and there was an SCM change...

Once XUnit was disabled, the issue went away.

===

Jenkins server: v1.432

XUnit plugin: v1.2.3